# How do I debug a python container in intellij?

Tags: python, docker, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

The docker plugin has a debug port for connecting to a container
[image]

I have a python application, but according to the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-docker-deployment.html) the debug port is only supported for java.

How can I set breakpoints and debug my python container in intellij? Is there some way I could have the python container connect to the intellij python debugger?

Edit: I'm running Windows 10, docker for Windows, and the container is linux. Perhaps I need to manually setup some kind of remote debugging for the intellij Python debugger? Also, might as well ask, must I have the professional version for remote debugging or is there a workaround using community?

Comment: Which Host OS are you using?

Comment: Windows is my OS, the container is Linux

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do that using Python Remote Debugging. Open the configurations window and click on + -> Python Remote Debug

[image: Python Debugger Option]

Then you either set a port or keep it blank for Pycharm to find a available port.

[image: Python Remote Debug]

Then click on Debug icon to launch the debug server which will show below kind of message

```
Starting debug server at port 57588
Use the following code to connect to the debugger:
import pydevd
pydevd.settrace('localhost', port=57588, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)
Waiting for process connection...
```

Now you need to setup pydev debugging inside docker. You will need the `pycharm-debug-py3k.egg` for this. For me I copied to my current Dockerfile folder like below

```
cp "/Users/tarun.lalwani/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea2017.2/python/pycharm-debug-py3k.egg" .
```

The location for your will change based on the IntelliJ version installed. After that, we need to edit our Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6
WORKDIR /app
ENV PYTHONPATH=/app:/app/debug
COPY pycharm-debug-py3k.egg /app/debug
COPY debug_test.py /app/
CMD python debug_test.py
```

The `debug_test.py` when built will have below lines at the top

```
import pydevd
pydevd.settrace('docker.for.mac.localhost', port=55507, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)
```

> Note: I have used `docker.for.mac.localhost` as I use docker for mac, but if use Docker for windows then use `docker.for.win.localhost`. For toolbox or linux you will add the IP of your machine

Since it is docker, we probably want to keep port fixed instead of dynamic like I did. Now we build the docker file and run it.

This will open a popup in pycharm, click autodetect to detect the source mappings

[image: Auto detect]

And then you will have your code breakpointed at the main line of your file

[image: Debug Local Execution Remote]

Comment: Is there a 3rd party plugin or something to be able to do this without professional or some other workaround?

Comment: I am not sure there is something like that for PyCharm but probably someone who has done extensive research in the area may know. Other option is to go for PyDev Eclipse or Visual Studio Code which as remote debugging for Python

Comment: pycharm-debug.egg for Python up to version 2

Comment: For Ultimate Edition users who can't find the Pycharm egg:  The Python debugger is available in PyPi so that it can be installed for doing remote debugging with pip.  When debugging a process that runs in another machine, it's possible to pip install pydevd instead of copying archives from debug-eggs directory under PyCharm's installation.